# Find index pairs in array whose value sum is equal to given sum

Tags: java, c, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have a method which accepts two parameters. 1st is an integer array and 2nd is an integer.

The method should print the index pairs where sum of the values present in those indexes equal to the 2nd input parameter.

The brute force approach is to have two loops which will take O(n^2) time. But I need to solve this in O(n) time.

The array can have repetitions and can have negative numbers also.

If it prints one pair then the reverse pair is not allowed. For example in the below sample if it should not print `(4,0), (3,2), (5,3)`

```
int[] arr = {3,4,-1,6,2,-1};
int sum = 5;
```

The method signature is :`findPairs(int[] arr, int sum);`

The output of this method will be : `(0,4), (2,3), (3,5)`

Explanation:

```
Element present at index 0 + Element present at index 4 = 3+2 = 5  
Element present at index 2 + Element present at index 3 = -1+6 = 5  
Element present at index 3 + Element present at index 5 = 6+-1 = 5
```

To clarify some confusions, I have tried using `HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>`. Here, key is the elements of array and value is their respective indices. As repetition is allowed, so for a given element there can be multiple index locations. So value in the map is a list.

Comment: Use efficient data structure like Map to solve the problem in `O(n)` time.

Comment: Using a map will help you to get this done in O(n). BTW, what's your question?

Comment: `findPairs(int[] arr, int sum);` I'm not sure what you mean here. If you are trying to call the function, then `findPairs(arr, sum);` will suffice.

Comment: @DeiDei i have given the method signature just for understanding purpose.

Comment: I have tried using HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>. Here key is the elements in array and value is their respective indexes. As repetition is allowed so for a given element there can be multiple index locations. So value in the hashmap is a list.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is absolutely correct.

Using **Map** does solve this problem in **O(n)**.

We will capitalise the benefits provided to us by JAVA by making use of **TreeMap** in this case. (Not necessary to be used).

**Also, the problem of repeated pairs of indices in the final answer can be solved using a visited map. This map checks if I have visited the particular index before. If yes, then I will not include it in my answer.**

Have a look the implementation below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    private static SortedMap<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String findPairs(int[] arr, int sum){

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            List<Integer> indexList = map.get(arr[i]);
            if(indexList == null){
                List<Integer> newIndexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                newIndexList.add(i);
                map.put(arr[i], newIndexList);
            }else{
                indexList.add(i);
            }
        }

        Set s = map.entrySet(); 

        HashMap<Integer, Boolean> visited = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

        // Using iterator in SortedMap 
        Iterator it = s.iterator(); 

        String finalOutput = "";

        while (it.hasNext()) 
        { 
            Map.Entry m = (Map.Entry)it.next(); 

            int key = (Integer)m.getKey(); 
            List<Integer> indexList1 = (List<Integer>)m.getValue();

            if(map.containsKey(sum-key)){

                List<Integer> indexList2 = (List<Integer>)map.get(sum-key);

                for(int i=0;i<indexList1.size();i++){

                    if(!visited.containsKey(indexList1.get(i))){

                        for(int j=0;j<indexList2.size();j++){
                            if(!(finalOutput.equals("") || finalOutput==null)){
                                finalOutput += ", ";
                            }
                            finalOutput += "(" + indexList1.get(i) + "," + indexList2.get(j) + ")";
                            visited.put(indexList2.get(j), true);
                        }
                        visited.put(indexList1.get(i), true);
                    }
                }
            } 
        }

        return finalOutput;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int[] arr = {3,4,-1,6,2,-1};
        int sum = 5;  

        Solution obj = new Solution();

        System.out.println(obj.findPairs(arr, sum));        
    }
}
```

Kindly feel free to ask doubts.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. But the code you have shared looks like is in O(n^3).

Answer (score 0):

```
public HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<List<Integer>>> getPairs(int[] input, int targetSum) {
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<List<Integer>>> hashMapList = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<List<Integer>>>();
    for(int i=0;i< input.length;i++) {
        //int j=i+1;
        for(int j=1;j< input.length;j++) {
            //if(j < input.length  && input[i] + input[j] == targetSum ) {
            if(i != j  && input[i] + input[j] == targetSum ) {
                ArrayList<List<Integer>> indexPairList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
                List<Integer> listPairs  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                if( null != hashMapList.get(targetSum)) {
                    indexPairList = hashMapList.get(targetSum);
                    for(List<Integer> listPair : indexPairList) {
                        listPairs.addAll(listPair);
                    }
                } 
                //System.out.println("listPairs - "+listPairs); 
                if(!listPairs.contains(i)
                        ||  (!listPairs.contains(j))) {
                    List<Integer> pair = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
                    pair.add(i);
                    pair.add(j);
                    indexPairList.add(pair);
                    hashMapList.put(targetSum, indexPairList);
                }                       
            }
        }
    }       
    return hashMapList;
}
```

Comment: would resolve the issue. Please try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code it should work**

```
import java.util.*;
public class FindPairAndIndexWithGivenSum {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] nums =  {1,2,3,7,6,3,3,9,2,3};
    int target = 8;

    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> ans= new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){

        int requiredNum=target - nums[i];
        if(map.containsKey(requiredNum)){
            String [] s=map.get(requiredNum)!=null?map.get(requiredNum).split(","):new String[1];

            if(s.length>1){
                String s1=s[0]+","+i;
                String s2 = s[1]+","+i;
                map.put(nums[i],s1);
                map.put(nums[i],s2);
                ans.add(s1+" : "+"("+nums[i]+","+requiredNum+") ");
                ans.add(s2+" : "+"("+nums[i]+","+requiredNum+") ");
            }else{

                map.put(nums[i],map.get(requiredNum)+","+i);
                ans.add(map.get(nums[i])+" : "+"("+nums[i]+","+requiredNum+") ");
            }




        }else{

            map.put(nums[i],String.valueOf(i));
        }

    }

    for (String a : ans){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).